# Version Control for untrusted team

Tags: dvcs, bazaar, code-access-security

I've been tasked with the redesign of a rather complex system. In a couple weeks we should start hiring new developers, but it turns out my boss is worried about them stealing the source code and selling it to his competitors. At the same time, my request for the implementation of a DVCS has been approved (we are moving away from the shared folder, yay!), so I'm wondering how can I reconcile differences between both concepts, by allowing developers to upload code to the main branch while keeping them away from the core functionality.

Is there any straightforward way of doing this? GIT seems to have something similar with the `filter-branch` command, but I was really looking forward to use Bazaar... From what I've gathered, the best way seems to be creating branches for each part of the system. Can anyone suggest a better way?

Comment: If your developers are untrusted you have more problems than your version control configuration.

Comment: It just came to my mind an online editor that displays asterisks when you type code...

Comment: How the heck can you develop without access to source code? Do everything in pieces and distribute dll/so? The concept itself is somewhat mind-boggling to me... What's wrong with an NDA in this case?

Comment: @Amadan - There's nothing wrong with NDA, the problem is management and that's off-topic here. It's an interesting question from the technical point of view, no matter how little sense it makes.

Comment: @robert: trust me, not only I think you are right, I *know* you are right, but as Álvaro says, I'm not the one making *that* decision.

Comment: @Amadan: since the system follows an MVC pattern, you can isolate those filthy thieves developers by assigning them the less important part (that would be the controller) and defining a common interface. And yes, there is an NDA too, but I can't write about it for obvious reasons :P

Comment: are you already have your code as bzr branch, or do you plan to adopt bzr? If you don't have bzr branch with long history yet, then it worth to split components of your system into separate branches, and then combine them into complex project with bzr-externals or scmproj plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need `filter-branch` equivalent you can use filter command from bzr-fastimport plugin.
But this will break compatibility between your old history and new one, so this is not the best approach maybe.

Comment: So if you already have a bazaar branch of every thing you can use `bzr split` to split them up into separate branches then filter out the stuff you don't want them to know. Then only give them access to branches and repositories that they are allowed to see.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via branching in mercurial (and git).  There are front facing products on top of these DVCS's that make this permissioning easy (see [Kiln](http://kilnhg.com), [BitBucket](http://bitbucket.com), private GitHub repos)

But robert's comment about your problems are true...  I'm worried about all the problems you are going to have if you don't trust devs that are committing source code to your repos.  How will they even compile their dev environment if they can't get your code?

Answer (score 1):

The better solution (IMHO) would be to expose the relevant binaries and create a consistent framework or API for extending the functionality of those binaries. The most you would have to expose to your untrusted sources would be the API layer which maintains hooks into the real code.

I actually think this is a really good question. Lots of people use contractors from outside their territory or country and its not unheard of for a contractor to steal code and go as far as to release a new (or counterfeit) product directly utilizing this code! VCS are meant to SHARE code though, so you need to think of other ways to restrict access.

Best of luck!